# Remove border when display property is set to none

Tags: html, css, border, display

This seems to be a simple task but for some reason I am having issues removing a border when the display property is set to none.

From what I've always understood is that when the display property is set to none it removes that element from the html flow.  However, in the example I've provided it still shows a border on the last element.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="control">Foo</div>
    <div class="control d-none">Bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6hfzpcoL/

Comment: The jsfiddle you linked shows that you're adding the border on the control with "Foo" not the "Bar" :not(:last-child) so you're doing that to every control class except the last child

Comment: Wouldn't "Foo" be considered the last child in this case since "Bar" is set to be removed from the html?  That's what I am having troubles with figuring out.

Comment: I agree with Gene. Are you trying to remove "Bar" block completely or remove border on "Foo"?

Comment: no the Bar elem is still there. the html is not removed. only not visible/rendered/

Comment: Your understanding about display:none is wrong. display:none will hide the element on the HTML but doesn't completely remove it.

Comment: Yeah I've always known the html is still there but somehow I thought the display property removed it from the html flow.  Ok so is there any way to target via css to remove the border on the last visible element even if one such as "Bar" is hidden via the display property?

Answer (score 2):

The 'd-none' element is still present, it is only not visible to the user. if you inspect the container you will see it is still there, so Foo isn't considered a last child - therefore border is still being applied.

What you are trying to achieve cannot be done with CSS only you would need to use Javascript or JQuery.